# Get Time From Date VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, date, time, format, clock

I am making an app which shows times of various countries in the world. The user can select the Timezone from the combobox and the time should be displayed in the Label. I'm using the following code to convert UTC time to selected timezone:

```
Dim ConvertedTime As Date = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(Date.UtcNow, CBTime1.SelectedItem)
```

CBTime1 lists all the timezones by the code:

```
Dim TimeZones As ReadOnlyCollection(Of TimeZoneInfo)
    TimeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
    CBTime1.BindingContext = New BindingContext
    CBTime1.DataSource = TimeZones
```

What should be the code to display the converted time in this format: 08:36:27 PM
I tried various codes but none worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a custom format string to format the time:

```
Dim formatted As String = ConvertedTime.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss tt")
```

Reference: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What does the ' means in the format? Won't it be the same if I type "hh:mm:ss tt"?

Comment: @Leeuwenhok: The apostrophes is to put a literal value in the format. The colon is the marker for the time separator, so the time separator character of the current culture would be used there. By making it a literal value it will always be a colon, regardless of the culture settings.

Comment: What is this culture you speak of? :p Btw, your code worked perfectly. I spent an hour trying to figure it out last night but couldn't. I tried stuff like first converting the Date to TimeSpan and then converting that to a string.format("hh:mm:ss") but it gave me an error of FormatException or something along those lines. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Leeuwenhok: When any data is formatted to a string, or parsed from a string, there is a culture setting involved. If you don't supply a `CultureInfo` object in the call (or a specific sub-object like `NumberFormatInfo` when formatting a number), the current culture setting of the application is used by default. You can use the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` propery to find out the default culture for the application.

Comment: @Leeuwenhok: If you want to accept the answer, there is a checkmark to the left of it that you can click.